# How to batch process geoTIFFs in R with lapply

Tags: r, lapply, r-raster

I have some large geoTIFFs, now I want to convert them to ASCII files, after doing some searches, I write these codes:

```
library(raster)

f <- list.files("inputFolder", pattern = "*.tif", full.names = TRUE)
r <- lapply(f, raster)
a <- lapply(r, writeRaster, filename = "output", format = "ascii")
```

What confused me is that how can I name the output files respectively, according to its original names?

I tried:

```
a <- lapply(r, writeRaster, filename = "outputFolder" + f, format = "ascii")
```

But I received error:

> non-numeric argument to binary operator

Then I tried:

```
a <- lapply(r, writeRaster, filename = paste0(f, ".asc"), format = "ascii")
```

But I received:

> Error in file(filename, "w") : invalid 'description' argument In
>   addition: Warning messages: 1: In if (filename == "") { :   the
>   condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 2: In
>   if (!file.exists(dirname(filename))) { :   the condition has length >
>   1 and only the first element will be used 3: In if
>   (toupper(x@file@name) == toupper(filename)) { :   the condition has
>   length > 1 and only the first element will be used 4: In if
>   (trim(filename) == "") { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the
>   first element will be used 5: In if (!file.exists(dirname(filename)))
>   { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be
>   used 6: In if (filename == "") { :   the condition has length > 1 and
>   only the first element will be used 7: In if (!overwrite &
>   file.exists(filename)) { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the
>   first element will be used

Comment: Can you provide a couple of example geoTIFFs for us to test?

Comment: I'd like to, but these examples are too large to be uploaded, so I provide you a similar one

Comment: http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/climate/cmip5/2_5m/cc26bi50.zip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you were basically nearly there, with two corrections:

First, you're calling `writeRaster` for its side effects (i.e. its ability to write a file to your filesystem) so you don't need to assign the output of your `lapply()` loop to an object. So, removing `a <-` we have:

```
lapply(r, writeRaster, filename = paste0(f, ".asc"), format = "ascii")
```

Next, the `filename` argument won't loop through `f` in this way. You have two options, of which the simplest is probably to pass the `@file@name` slot of `r` to the `filename` argument using an anonymous function:

```
lapply(r, function(x) {
  writeRaster(x, filename = x@file@name, format = "ascii", overwrite = TRUE)
})
```

Your other option would be to loop through `r` and `f` in parallel like you can in python with `for r, f in...`, which can be done with `purrr`:

```
library("purrr")
walk2(r, f, function(x, y) {
  writeRaster(x = x, filename = y, format = "ascii")
})
```

Here we're using `walk2()` rather than `map2()` because we need to call the function for side effects. This loops through `r` and `f` together so you can pass one to be the object to write, and one to be the filename.

---

Edit: here's the code I use to reproduce the problem

```
library("raster")

tmp_dir = tempdir()
tmp     = tempfile(tmpdir = tmp_dir, fileext = ".zip")

download.file(
  "http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/climate/cmip5/10m/cc26bi50.zip",
  destfile = tmp
)
unzip(tmp, exdir = tmp_dir)

f = list.files(tmp_dir, pattern = ".tif$", full.names = TRUE)
r = lapply(f, raster)

# Solution one
lapply(r, function(x) {
  writeRaster(x, filename = x@file@name, format = "ascii", overwrite = TRUE)
})

# solution two
library("purrr")
walk2(r, f, function(x, y) {
  writeRaster(x = x, filename = y, format = "ascii")
})
```

Comment: It is better to use `filename(x)` instead of x@file@name

Comment: It seems that purrr is an essential package to learn, I'll look for some documents, thanks

Comment: @RobertH I've never really come across `filename()` before. Why is it preferred over just accessing a slot? Thanks

Comment: It is best to consider slots as 'private' to the object and use methods to get or set their values. This is because if a value in a slot is changed, values in other slots may need to change too. This is generally not an issue with reading slot values, but it can be (e.g. when reading values from a Raster object). It is better to use methods as these will do sanity checking of the values as needed and this will lead to more reliable code. I consider it a 'contract' that values returned by methods like 'filename' wont change over time, but internal workings and slotnames of a class may change.

Comment: Of course there are some cases where you legitimately need to use direct access to a S4 slot. For example if the package developers have not provided methods to get or set values. But even then you should consider whether that is because they did not think it was necessary to write such methods (and that is common enough), or because they thought you should not change the values.  I believe the raster package has methods from all user-level relevant slots.

Comment: @RobertH Thanks, very interesting food for thought. Always worth trying to make things more robust.

Answer (score 1):

To test how to do this with small files:

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
writeRaster(s, file='testtif', format='GTiff', bylayer=T, overwrite=T)
f <- list.files(pattern="testtif_..tif")
```

Now you can use `f` with Phil's nice examples. You can also combine all in one step lapply:

```
f <- list.files("inputFolder", pattern = "*.tif", full.names = TRUE)
r <- lapply(f, function(i) { writeRaster(raster(i), filename=extension(i, '.asc'), overwrite=TRUE)} )
```

But if you have trouble with lapply, write a loop (it is fine!):

```
for (i in 1:length(f)) {
   r <- raster(f[i])
   ff <- extension(f[i], '.asc')
   writeRaster(r, ff)
}
```

Or like this

```
for (file in f) {
   r <- raster(file)
   ff <- extension(file, '.asc')
   writeRaster(r, ff)
}
```

Comment: filename(x) is very useful! I'm not familiar with x@file@name, is there any document?

Comment: x@file@name is not documented because you are not supposed to use it.

Comment: @TianjianQin `@file@name` is an `S4` slot based on the data you supplied. You can check the structure of your data with `str()`